# Session Storage not working after migrating to Manifest V3 - Chrome Extension

Tags: manifest, session-storage

New to Chrome extension.

Session Storage return null from after migrate from manifest V2 to version 3. And trying chrome storage but not really make it work. Appreciate any advise.

--this is working version in manifest V2.

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch ( request.method ) {
        case "setData":
            saveData( request.dataName, request.data );
            break;
        case "getData":
            sendResponse( getData( request.dataName ) );
            return true;
        default:
            sendResponse({}); // snub them.*/
            break;
    }
});

function getData ( dataName ) {
    return ({ data: JSON.parse( sessionStorage.getItem( dataName ) ) });
}

function saveData ( dataName, dataIn ) {
    // When copying the forms across, re-instate all data (new state)
    if ( dataName === 'archetype' ) {
        sessionStorage.clear();
    }
    sessionStorage.setItem( dataName, JSON.stringify( dataIn ) );
}
```

Change to this but giving error but no data has been capture on chrome.storage.session getdata method.

//manifest added storage
"permissions": [
"declarativeContent",
"activeTab",
"storage"
],

//Background.js

```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch ( request.method ) {
        case "setData":
            saveData( request.dataName, request.data );
            break;
        case "getData":
            getData( request.dataName, function(result){ sendResponse(result); } );
            return true;
        default:
            sendResponse({}); // snub them.*/
            break;
    }
});

 function getData ( dataName, callback ) {
var myreturn = chrome.storage.session.get( dataName );
    if (callback) {
    JSON.parse(chrome.storage.session.get( dataName )).then(callback);
}

}

function saveData ( dataName, dataIn ) {
    if ( dataName === 'archetype' ) {
        chrome.storage.session.clear();
    }
    chrome.storage.session.set( dataName, JSON.stringify( dataIn ) );
}
```